# Maxmind GeoIP Country/City MySQL Open-Source Alternative

Tags: mysql, open-source, geocoding

Is there an open-source alternative to MaxMind GeoIP Country/City that I can use for MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GeoLite City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) and [GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) are usable under

```
All advertising materials and documentation mentioning features or use of
this database must display the following acknowledgment:
"This product includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from
http://maxmind.com/"
```

which is not open source of course, but may help you to get started.

The API:

```
The GeoIP C Library is licensed under the LGPL.
```

Some open source efforts are [listed on Virtual Terrain](http://www.vterrain.org/Culture/geocoding.html).

And some java ip resolver: http://javainetlocator.sourceforge.net/